# Problems with Geolocation's asynchronous call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, geolocation

I'm trying to send my location as an Ajax request.
Probably due to geolocation's asynchronous call, it doesn't work as intended.
Geolocation's function is called after my outer functions, resulting in a `data is empty` answer.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {

        var data = "";

        if (...) { // if user wants to share their location
            function geo_success(position) {
                console.info("lat:" + position.coords.latitude + " Lot: " + position.coords.longitude);
                data = {
                    lat : position.coords.latitude,
                    lon : position.coords.longitude
                };
            }

            function geo_error() {
                alert("No position available.");
            }

            var geo_options = {
                enableHighAccuracy : true,
                timeout : 1000,
                maximumAge : 0
            };

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geo_success, geo_error, geo_options);
        }
        if (...) { // if user doesn't want to share their location
            data = {
                a : "abc", // some other data
                b : "def"
            };
        }
        if (...) { // maybe a third option
            data = {
                b : "test", // some other data
                c : "some data"
            };
        }

        if (Object.keys(data).length > 0) {
            console.info("hier");
            $.ajax({
                method : "GET",
                url : "test.php",
                data : data, // finaly send data
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function(data) {
                    console.log(data)
                },
                error : function(data) {
                    console.error(data);
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.error("data is empty");
        }
    });
});

<input type="checkbox" id="box1" />
<button>ok</button>
```

I can't put the Ajax request in `geo_success`, because `data` needs to be defined first. In my original code (here is just an extract), there are several possible `data`, depending on the user's choice.
So I want to have 1 Ajax request only.

What could be a possible remedy?

Comment: *"I can't put the Ajax request in geo_success, because I need to define data first."* – I just can't see how these two things are related.

Comment: Put the ajax in geo_success after you've set `data`

Comment: Create `promise` which will resolved in `geo_success` and rejected in `geo_error`. Then build your logic in `.then` or `.catch`.

Comment: @Juhana: There are several `data` possible.

Comment: @JaromandaX: The user not always wants to share its location. Please see my update.

Comment: Create a function that handles the ajax. Call it at the various places data is defined passing data as the argument

Comment: @JaromandaX: Could you please show me how?

Comment: Can't you simply put the if/else conditional statement in your geo success function? The reason is because AJAX is asynchronous so before any data is received from your call, the browser has already evaluated the conditional statement.

Comment: @Terry: As already mentioned, I don't know, if the user wants to share their location. If not, another if-statement will trigger and `data` will get other parameters.

Comment: Then move your logic around. If the user does not consent, overwrite the original data object with test data.

Answer (score 0):

> Probably due to geolocation's asynchronous call, it doesn't work as intended. Geolocation's function is called after my outer functions, resulting in a data is empty answer.

So you mean this is an asynchronous call?:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geo_success, geo_error, geo_options);
```

If that's the case then I suspect you could supply it with call-back functions to execute when the operation is complete.  And... It looks like you're already doing that...

```
function geo_success(position) {
    console.info("lat:" + position.coords.latitude + " Lot: " + position.coords.longitude);
    data = {
        lat : position.coords.latitude,
        lon : position.coords.longitude
    };
}

function geo_error() {
    alert("No position available.");
}
```

So if you need to respond to the results of the asynchronous operation, just put that code in those call-back functions.

Asynchronous means just that... *not* synchronous.  Anything that needs to happen after an asynchronous operation needs to be invoked *by* that operation when it completes.  In your case `data` will always be empty when you examine it because you explicitly set it to an empty string when you created it, and nothing else has updated it at that time.

Comment: So what could be a solution?

Comment: @user1170330: Is the solution I proposed not working in some way?

Comment: If I understood you right, you were just describing the problem. Did I miss your solution?

Comment: @user1170330: Sorry about that, I've updated the answer.  Basically, any code which needs to respond to the results of the asynchronous operation would go in the call-back functions.